# Feynman's Diagram contribution in Green's Function

Tags: feynman-diagrams, many-body, greens-functions, phonons

I was reading **Many Particle Physics by G. Mahan** and they calculated the Green's function for electron-phonon interaction using Feynman's Diagram. It was written that Green's function contribution by diagram (c), (d) and (e) will be zero because they exist only if $q_1$ is zero. The reason they gave was that a phonon with $q=0$ is either a translation of the crystal or a permanent strain. Therefore neither of these are meant to be in Hamiltonian. Though I understand the reasoning, I am still not convinced why it will have no contribution in the Green's Function. Can someone give a good argument over this statement?

[image]

Comment: Why are (a) and (b) different? We are integrating over all possible values of $q_1$ aren't we?

Comment: That's a good question. I can't write the full derivation of Hamiltonian of phonons but can say that $H \sim (a_q+a^{\dagger}_{-q})$ to make the Hamiltonian hermitian. If you want to know more, I suggest you read about the theory of electron-phonon interaction.

Comment: I did the calculations and yes they both are the same by calculation.

Comment: Since this question hasn't received an answer, could you please try it at [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)? I think the chances of getting an answer would be greater since that site is exclusively for advanced-level questions like this, and doesn't have any high-school-level homework questions occupying the users time.